# Project Directory Structure Problem in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, project-structure

I am facing this weird problem ..When i checked out project from svn my whole project was in directory kind of structure

ie. my package was like  (folder inside another folder)

MainProject
+
+
+++project_1_name
++++++++src
++++++++++++com
++++++++++++++companyname
++++++++++++++++++ClassName
+
+++project_2_name
++++++++src
++++++++++++com
++++++++++++++companyname
++++++++++++++++++ClassName

but i want it to be like

MainProject
+
project_1_name
+++++src.com.companyname.className
project_2_name
+++++src.com.companyname.className

when i am importing a particular sub project from the main project separately on my workspace then the project is appearing as package structure as i see..I am using eclipse for the first time ..Kindly pardon me for asking some thing stupid like this ..But please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: This should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The structure/folder hierarchy is as expected, a java package is a folder.

In Eclipse, Package Explorer, click on a small arrow-like icon pointing downwards and select Package Presentation 'Flat' or 'Hierarchical'.

Possibly you would like to have 'Flat'.

Comment: you are right Kennet i checked my setting and it is checked as flat only still i am getting hierarchical structure... ;( neway thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want the Package Explorer view instead of the Navigator view?

`Window > Show View > Package Explorer`

Or maybe you want the Project Explorer view:

`Window > Show View > Project Explorer`

Either of those views has a "flat" and a "hierarchical" package style. The "flat" package style sounds like what you want.

Comment: Actually it seems to me like it's the other way around.

Comment: @Anupam That's what the Package Explorer view can do. You may also need to change from the hierarchical view to the flat view, as @Kennet describes in his answer.

Comment: @Shaded I'm pretty sure Anupam is asking for the flat view in the Package Explorer. I don't see an option for a flat view in the Navigator view.

Comment: *shrug* I honestly don't really know the difference between the two, I always use Hierarchal Package Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

When you import projects from SVN, after selecting the base url, you should check the "find projects in the children of the selected resource" box.