# project directory structure related issue

Tags: eclipse, maven, project, directory-structure

I already posted one question earlier
[Project Directory Structure Problem in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718878/project-directory-structure-problem-in-eclipse) 
but couldn't get satisfactory answer.
So posting the question again with image and making myself more clear

[image]

I am trying to import the maven project in eclipse.. can any one please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding Aarons comment about m2eclipse: Check the Checkout All Projects option when checking out your project (Use checkout as Maven Project from the SVN Repositories view):

[image]

[image]

It is really that simple, as long as your root pom references all your modules.

Comment: HI Travis thanks a lot!! I have helios installed with m2eclipse and subclipse. When attempting to "Checkout a Maven Project from SCM" for the drop down list "SCM URL" the box has no options listed. I tried entering "scm:svn:svn://<svn repo url>/producta" (a valid location) on the second drop down I simply get a message in the maven console: "SCM provider is not available for scm:svn:<svn repo url>/producta"

I have also tried http though I am using the svn protocol to no effect as well. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could cause this and specifically how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You may choose to use the context menu of the repository in question from the SVN Repositories View (if you have added this repository to there). Who is this Travis guy you are talking about ;)?

Comment: he he he ... sorry torsten I donno from where this name i typed I was googling many sites may be some  where else i would have seen this name and typed by mistake ...

Comment: I tried as you told and steps are shown at ... [link](http://i.imgur.com/Guxcp.png) ...this image will explain my problem

Comment: does this issue still exist as a bug as mentioned [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1353)

Comment: Added image that illustrates the way to reach this

Comment: Thanks Again Torsten I got it now my problem was M2eclipse was not properly installed so now i imported the mvn project properly but i have one last issue left which i have tried to explain **[here](http://i.imgur.com/uCtzn.png)** please help me with the last doubts mentioned in the image... If you can answer my these questions then i definitely owe you more than one beer....

Comment: Yes, those projects all share one source tree. If you build the top level project it will also build all its modules, which are the projects which appeared as seperate projects. Bonus Answer: If you add other modules later, you can generate the eclipse projects from them by right-clicking on your toplevel project and selecting Import... Maven / Existing Maven Projects.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the proper Java source path in your project properties under Java Build Path.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open the Java perspective in Eclipse to get the right view. This happens to me if I have the PyDev perspective open.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must import `*impl` as a Maven project (i.e. you must import each module individually). Eclipse doesn't support recursive projects ([bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=245412)).

**[EDIT]**

When you tell Eclipse to "import the project" make sure to **deselect "Copy into workspace"**. That way, there will be only a single place where all the files are.

Comment: @Optimizer: Actually M2Eclipse is able to import cascaded maven projects into several Eclipse Projects.

Comment: @Torsten: Post an answer which explains how to do that for a +1

Comment: @Aaron - Thanks a lot for your reply!!!!!! But as you can see for my single project I have multiple sub-projects for which I have one parent POM.xml now my problem is when I am importing them individually I am not able to bind them together through my parent POM ... moreover if I will import them separately then i wont be able to build the whole project again inside my eclipse..how will i be able to tackle that problem?????

Comment: I have tried explaining [my problem over here](http://i.imgur.com/uCtzn.png) can you please help

Comment: @Anupam: When you tell Eclipse to "import the project" make sure to **deselect** "copy into workspace". That way, there will be only a single place where all the files are. Any change in either main or any module will actually change a single file -> both items in Eclipse will update. What's confusing is when you search for a resource because you will get duplicate results. But building and editing will work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

After checking out multi-module project:

1. **Import each project into workspace** using *`File>Import>General>Existing Maven Projects`*. All modules should appear as individual top-level projects in your workspace.
2. If your projects don't already have source folders confgiured - configure them using *`{your project}>Properties/Java Build Path> Source`*